# Find the number of ways to get a total of 10.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

My math teacher was explaining a question in the chapter Combinatorics and I met with a hiccup in the solution. The question is given below and the solution (as given by my teacher) is also given in the form of a screenshot of the zoom meeting.

$3$ dices are rolled simultaneously once and the resulting numbers are added. Find the number of ways of getting a total of $10$.

[The solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJxOH.png)

The hiccup is that I cant understand how [the last line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TecvK.jpg) is equal to the [one before it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49V6r.jpg).

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: They are certainly not equal. I think your teacher simply omitted the terms with higher powers ($x^{12}, x^{18}$) since they do not contribute to the coefficient of $x^7$.

Comment: Thanks a lot.... And I am new to the community so I cant use MathJax that's why I had to use picture links, will keep that in mind.

Comment: @SupragyaMishra: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a basic MathJax tutorial.

Comment: Thanks @BrianM.Scott

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{}}$

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\sum_{d_{1} = 1}^{6}\sum_{d_{2} = 1}^{6}\sum_{d_{3} = 1}^{6}
\bracks{z^{10}}z^{d_{1}\ +\ d_{2}\ +\ d_{3}}} =
\bracks{z^{10}}\pars{\sum_{d_{1} = 1}^{6}z^{d}}^{3} =
\bracks{z^{10}}\pars{z\,{z^{6} - 1 \over z - 1}}^{3}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{7}}\pars{1 - z^{6}}^{3}\pars{1 - z}^{-3} =
\bracks{z^{7}}\pars{1 - 3z^{6}}\pars{1 - z}^{-3}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{7}}\pars{1 - z}^{-3} -
3\bracks{z^{1}}\pars{1 - z}^{-3} =
{-3 \choose 7}\pars{-1}^{7} - 3{-3 \choose 1}\pars{-1}^{1}
\\[5mm] = &\
{9 \choose 7} - 3{3 \choose 1} = 36 - 3 \times 3 = \bbx{27} \\ &
\end{align}